# Fetching only message headers from Gmail

Tags: java, performance, google-api, gmail-api

I'm writing an small app to generate stats in a GMail inbox to help with the endless task of cleaning our mailbox.

My code is working, but I am unnecessarily download messages's payload data to access only the message headers (From field header).

The method [Gmail.Users.Messages.Get.setFields(String)](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/gmail/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/gmail/Gmail.Users.Messages.Get.html#setFields(java.lang.String)) with payload option, but payload is exactly the heaviest part  of it. I already tried using values like "payload.header", "payload.headers", but none of these values work.

So the question is, how can I access only message's from field instead of fetching entire payload data in order to improve performance?

```
    Map<String, Integer> emailAddressCountMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    for (Message message : messages) {
        Message m1 = service.users().messages().get(user, message.getId()).setFields("payload").execute();

        Stream<String> fromHeaderValue = m1.getPayload().getHeaders().stream()
                .filter(h -> "From".equals(h.getName())).map(h -> h.getValue());

        String emailAddress = fromHeaderValue.toArray(String[]::new)[0];
        Integer count = emailAddressCountMap.get(emailAddress);
        if (count == null) {
            count = 0;
        }
        emailAddressCountMap.put(emailAddress, count + 1);

        System.out.println(emailAddress + ": " + count);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a following modification?

#### From :

```
Message m1 = service.users().messages().get(user, message.getId()).setFields("payload").execute();
```

#### To :

```
Message m1 = service.users().messages().get(user, message.getId()).setFields("payload/headers").execute();
```

If this didn't work, or if I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Yes, it works! We can also use payload[headers] as per this GMail API performance guide. 
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/performance

Thanks!

Comment: @Rafael Borja Welcome. Thank you, too. I'm glad I could be useful for you.

Comment: By the way, @tanaike, you can find the complete source code at https://github.com/rafaelborja/GmailInboxStats for an small script to list the highest number of unread messages in a gmail mailbox. 

Thanks!

Comment: @Rafael Borja Thank you for the additional information.